# How to add a user editable text label for a row of text input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically generating a grid of input fields from an input in a drop down menu. However i am not able to add a user editable text label for each row to represent what the row means. I am also trying to label each column of the grid 1...5. A fiddle of what i currently have. http://jsfiddle.net/p_kish/qspzz/1/
Any way i try messes the grid up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an additional column and row with the labels.  Once the label is clicked (looks like you're using jQuery so just set a `$("label").click(function(){...})` handler), simply replace that label with an input box that allows them to edit the label.  On `blur` swap the `input` back to a `label` with the value from the `input`.

Comment: Thats the problem. In the code, im not creating a rows and columns. I'm creating just a sequence of text inputs in a for loop and putting in a <br> to create the illusion that it is a grid. I didn't know any other way of doing it.

Comment: Its a formatting issue at that point.  Is there a particular reason you aren't using a table?  Table's aren't always "bad".  They are still intended for tabular data (they're just "bad" when their used for layout). I would consider this tabular data.  If you really don't want to use a table, you should make the labels and inputs `display:block` and float them left.  Then make each row its own div.  You can see how that is a lot messier though.

Comment: Yeah, I have just experimented with putting them into tables when i'm building the text boxes but because of the way i'm generating them, it's not really feasible to do it. It messes up the layout pretty badly. I'm checking if it would be easier to put the text fields and labels in different divs